# Quadcopter Roll, Pitch Fluctuation

Tags: quadcopter

For my quadcopter, i turn on the quadcopter while letting it stable on the ground. But i see that the Roll, Pitch fluctuate with the max difference being 15 degree. When i protect the sensor with soft material, then i observe the max difference is around 6 degree. Is this fluctuation for the quadcopter? By the way, i use complementary filter and DCM with scaling factor being 0.8 gyro and 0.2 accel
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your drift is high. What is the oscillation period?

Comment: Also what is the frequency of your DCM filter? The accel coefficient looks high (my quadcopter is airworthy and the accel coefficient at 200Hz is 0.005).

Answer (score 3):

Very nice question ,

Kindly check EMF and make sure to isolate the MPU9150 from any EMF and Make sure that it's temperature is Stable and change in the temperature will lead to huge drift in reading regardless the filter you are using

Comment: Can you give me some example of EMF sources that can affect the sensor?

Comment: any lines with current passing near by it, any battery , any metal , and so ..you need to fully isolate it

Comment: Sorry, but how can we isolate it from any source of EMF. Does commercial quad also have to do so!

Comment: I don't know ...

Answer (score 0):

What imu combination do you use to measure the roll and pitch? Do you use a fusion algorithm to correct for drift? Personally I think the drift values that you report are far to big.

Comment: I use DCM algorithm along with complimentary filter. The sensor is MPU9150 which has Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer